# Angular ng-class slow to load background image?

Tags: css, angularjs, background-image

I'm using ng-click to change the background image of a span tag. On changing the image the first time, it takes a second or two to load. But then alternating back and forth between the images is perfect. Both images are approx. 500 bytes so I don't think size is an issue.

I'm working on an angular app for mobile. In my mobile emulator in chrome, the images load perfectly. It is only on a mobile device that the problem appears.

```
    <div class="data_table" ng-click="collapsed = !collapsed">
        <table>
        <tr class="top_row">
              <td>
                <div>
                    Data
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span ng-class="!collapsed ? 'collapse_icon' : 'expand_icon'"></span>
              </td>
       </tr>
   </div>



.collapse_icon {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
    width: 5%;
    color: #000;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background-image: url(../images/collapse2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.expand_icon {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
    width: 5%;
    color: #000;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background-image: url(../images/expand2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

So is this just a mobile issue or am I using the wrong directive?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an issue with angular or directive itself. There is a lot of things that can affect the performance. If you believe your device can run that smoothly, you can inspect what's going on under the hood via Timeline in Chrome's debugger.

Also you should not rely on Chrome's emulator for performance as it does not reflect that. It is useful for html/css part.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping it was the code and not another factor that may be harder to track down. :)

Answer (score 1):

the issue is with the ng-model binding, Also you should not rely on Chrome's emulator for performance as it does not reflect that. It is useful for html/css part.